# AS3: Array [A term is undefined and has no properties.]

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I'm using array for storing some values then pass it to the summary page.. But its saying that "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.".. This error appears when I place the code of "_CombosNameAllArray.splice(0);". I used this because I want to empty the _CombosNameAllArray so that when it proceed to summary page it will not display so many variables.  But when I trace the _CombosNameAllArray it has a value...

Here's my code for first frame:

```
_CombosNameAllArray.splice(0);
repeat();
```

then for repeat

```
_CombosNameAllArray[_ACounter] = "A";
```

So i think it has a value after it load the repeat();

then for second frame:

```
for(var p = 1; p<_CombosNameAllArray.length;p++)    
{
var textArray:Array = new Array();
var textPrice:Array = new Array();

textArray[p] = new TextField();
textArray[p].text = _CombosNameAllArray[p].toString(); //this is the error
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: first off, trace `_CombosNameAllArray.length` at the begining of scond frame and tell us what the value is. How are you persisting _CombosNameAllArray over the frames?

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r...I already found a way out I just fix the value.but then I still want to know how to fix this for my future reference...What if the result is 1? nor the result is 0??

Comment: not sure what you're getting at m8. pls try and explain again

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the _CombosNameAllArray is completely empty.

If you start p at 0 the error won't appear.

```
trace("_CombosNameAllArray.length: "+_CombosNameAllArray.length);

for(var p:int = 0; p<_CombosNameAllArray.length; p++)
```

Comment: @crooksy88....I started p at 1 because its also copy the word "None", and I think its because when I declare this in my as a var "_CombosNameAllArray:Array=["None"];"...

Comment: If you trace the length of _CombosNameAllArray before the for loop what do you get? How many items are in the array?

Comment: @crooksy88...I already found a way out I just fix the value.but then I still want to know how to fix this for my future reference...What if the result is 1? nor the result is 0??

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're aiming for. But you could test to see if the length of the array is greater than 1 before running the for statement. if (_CombosNameAllArray.length > 1) {}